# How many different ways you can choose K elements from array of size n but without duplicates

Tags: c#

Basically I want to know how i can remove the duplicates from the ways i can choose k from array of n

This is my code which shows all possible combinations with duplicates for e.g 32 , 32 ,33 , 22 , 23 , 23:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Techniques
{

public static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        int[] data = { 3, 2, 2, 3 };
        int k = 2;
        foreach (string comb in CombinationsOfK(data, k).Select(c => string.Join(" ", c)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(comb);
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CombinationsOfK<T>(T[] data, int k)
    {
        int size = data.Length;

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Runner(IEnumerable<T> list, int n)
        {
            int skip = 1;
            foreach (var headList in list.Take(size - k + 1).Select(h => new T[] { h }))
            {
                if (n == 1 )
                    yield return headList;
                else
                {
                    foreach (var tailList in Runner(list.Skip(skip), n - 1))
                    {
                        
                       
                            yield return headList.Concat(tailList);
                        
                    }
                    skip++;
                }
            }
        }

        return Runner(data, k);
    }
}
}
```

I want to know how can i remove duplicates from the combinations i get for e.g 23 , 22, 33 no two combinations should be same.

Comment: You're emitting a string, at the end? I believe there's a LINQ  `.Distinct()` method that will strip out duplicates. Would that be the most elegant solution? No.

Comment: im using a for each loop to get individual elements i dont know how distinct will work in this

Comment: I'll put what I mean in an answer, with an example.

Comment: Are you forbidden to sort the input? Or to use other data types along the way? You could try using a `HashSet<T>` as a cache of each combination you've found so far, and not return a combination if it was already in the cache.  You might have to use a value type for your combinations, though. I *think* that a simple array would work, but test it.

Comment: i think that might work the distinct one is a feature so its like im cheating soo i think this might work actually ill try

Comment: Report back! I'll update my answer to include the `HashSet<T>` suggestion.

Comment: yes update youre answer

Comment: @AnnL. can u just tell me how can i Use HashSet in this no need to send the whole code for this

Comment: Sorry for the delay: I had to make a phone call. I've updated my answer with an explanation of how to use HashSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion, for a Q&D solution:

You've got this code, printing out the combinations:

```
foreach (string comb in CombinationsOfK(data, k).Select(c => string.Join(" ", c)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(comb);
}
```

The end result of this clause:

```
CombinationsOfK(data, k).Select(c => string.Join(" ", c))
```

... will be an `IEnumerable<string>`. And you can apply `Distinct` to that, and the strings will be thinned out based on their value as strings.

So:

```
var combStrings = CombinationsOfK(data, k).Select(c => string.Join(" ", c));
foreach (var comb in combStrings.Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine(comb);
}
```

A disclaimer, though: I'm doing this from memory, and can't test the code from this machine.

ALSO: if this is a course assignment, and part of the assignment is to prevent duplicates, your instructor may consider this an invalid solution, because it's taking advantage of a feature of how strings are treated, rather than refining your algorithm.

ETA: An answer using a cache (a `HashSet<T>`):

You're going to have to restructure your code somewhat, or put checks against your cache in several places (before each `yield`).

Basically, every time you know what value you want to `yield`, check it vs. the cache.

Define the cache somewhere (maybe right after you define `size`):

```
var cache = HashSet<string>();
```

You'll be using strings in the cache, because comparisons involving them use value-based comparing. I was wrong, earlier, when I thought that was also true of `int[]`.

Then, everywhere you have `yield return`, wrap it with this:

```
var cacheValue = <whatever you were going to return>.Select(c => string.Join(" ", c));
if(!cache.Contains(cacheValue))
{
   cache.Add(cacheValue);
   yield return <whatever you were going to return>;
}
```

Comment: i Cant actually add the cacheValue in Cache I cant add IEnumerable to Hashset it seems

Comment: its ok i can use this where i return things ill use a hashset to get all thecombinations from the Function and then print it out that works

Comment: Thankyou soo much